# Why Ferrites are used as a cores for inductors

Tags: inductor, ferrite

Why specifically we use the ferrites as a core for the inductors? For example a NiZn toroid as a core for an inductor?

Comment: Because they have a higher resistivity than metals and are cheaper than powder cores.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me until I made some research, but I believe OP is talking about "Nickel-zinc ferrite", \$\text{Ni$_a$Zn$_{(1-a)}$Fe$_2$O$_4$}\$, (found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_core)) and not Nickel-Zinc batteries.

Comment: What have you read so far? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_core  and https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/ferrite_ni-zn_material_characteristics_en.pdf  There are two material types and MANY variations of both.

Comment: Which other magnetic materials (and their electromagnetic properties) did you research before asking this question?

Comment: Hint: as mentioned by others, eddy effects are the main reason. Note how low-frequency AC inductors use *laminated* Si-steel cores, and then consider what happens as frequency increases. Ferrites are made of *very* small particles.sintered together.

Answer (score 0):

Permeability and saturation affect maximum field strength, operating current, and energy per pulse.  Higher resistance/separation/layering of materials are used to reduce eddy current losses.  The higher the frequency, the less inductance is necessary, so air core or PCB trace inductors see use in some applications.  The promising sounding but potentially difficult to control [resonant cuk converter](https://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/benchtalk/4460524/Cuk-s-resonant-buck-slashes-magnetics) may be able to operate at significant power levels with PCB trace inductors, even at low frequencies.  If the factors of scale being talked about pan out, physical size of power converters could decrease by an order of magnitude.  There are reasons to use ferrite(apparently high resistivity/permeability and low cost to manufacture), but it is far from the only material used.  Each core material has a viable frequency range and energy density and when the goal is known, as it often is in engineering applications, it becomes as much a question of which type is necessary as of which type is best.